# How to configure http cache policy on an Azure CDN (Premium Verizon) enpoint with storage origin?

Tags: azure, cache-control, http-caching, azure-cdn

We have an Azure CDN profile with Premium Verizon pricing tier. In this profile we have 2 CDN enpoints. One of them has custom origin type, which refers a web app. Second one has a storage origin type.

First endpoint is serving files with HTTP cache, with these settings:

```
cache-control: public,max-age=31536000
```

But second endpoint is not serving the files with any cache policy. We haven't configured anything about http caching on cdn endpoint settings or Verizon Rules Engine.

Why there isn't any cache policy on the cdn endpoint with storage origin? Is this an expected behaviour of storage origin type? How can we fix that?